# What will be the value of this limit?

Tags: limits

I need help solving this limit.
$$ \large \lim_{x\to \infty} ([(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)]^{\frac 13} -x) $$

I have tried rationalizing and then dividing the numerator and the denominator by $x^3$ but that doesn't work. I still get a $\frac 00$ form.

All help will be appreciated

Comment: Which integral?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos LoL, Sorry I meant limit :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Applying the identity

$$\sqrt[3]u-v=\frac{u-v^3}{(\sqrt[3]u)^2+\sqrt[3]u\,v+v^2},$$

you understand that the numerator will be a polynomial with leading term $(a+b+c)x^2$, and the denominator will be a sum of three terms each asymptotic to $x^2$, hence

$$\frac{a+b+c}3.$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Comment: I used this and then divided the num and denom by $x^3$ that still gave me the $\frac 00$ form

Comment: Then Show us your calculations!

Comment: I checked my calculations, and it turned out I made a mistake and retained that $x^3$ term. All good now. Thanks for the Answer!! +1

Comment: I wish you a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x)=x^n+rx^{n-1}+\cdots$$
be a monic polynomial of degree $n$. Then
$$f(x)^{1/n}
=x(1+rx^{-1}+O(x^{-2}))^{1/n}
=x(1+(r/n)x^{-1}+O(x^{-2}))$$
and so
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)^{1/n}-x)=\frac rn.$$

In your example, $f(x)=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer, thanks for answering one of my questions again!

Answer (score 1):

$$\large \lim_{x\to \infty} ([(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)]^{\frac 13} -x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} (x(1+\frac{a}{x})^{\frac 13}(1+\frac{b}{x})^{\frac 13}(1+\frac{c}{x})^{\frac 13} -x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} (x(1+\frac{a}{3x}+O(1/x^2))(1+\frac{b}{3x}+O(1/x^2))(1+\frac{c}{3x}+O(1/x^2)) -x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} (x(1+\frac{a+b+c}{3x}+O(1/x^2))-x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a+b+c}{3}+O(\frac{1}{x})$$
$$=\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

Comment: Ah, I see! +1 Thanks! It helped